# swt Layout equivalent to css subgrid

Tags: layout, html-table, swt, subgrid

Css subgrids (CSS Grid Layout Module Level 2) are useful to simplify complex layouts.

See for example:

https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2017/07/20/why-display-contents-is-not-css-grid-layout-subgrid/ or
https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Tutorials/Grid/Verschachtelte_Raster

Can similar behaviour be implemented as  [org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Layout](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Eclipse/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Layout.html)  for nested Composites?

Comment: Are you asking if you could write your own Layout to do this or are you asking if an existing Layout can do it? Either way this is too broad.  `GridLayout` is probably the closest existing layout.

Comment: Well i would prefer an existing solution. But any hint to implement some would be welcome.